# How to install sicktoolbox in Kinetic?

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, sicktoolbox-wrapper

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I am trying to install sicktoolbox and sicktoolbox_wrapper in Kinetic, and am hitting a wall on building dependencies and compiling the driver. Could you please let me know what I am doing wrong?

Here are the steps I am taking:

1. sicktoolbox download – The home page for this package is (https://wiki.ros.org/sicktoolbox), and the download location is: (https://github.com/ros-drivers/sicktoolbox/tree/catkin). I made sure to download the ‘catkin’ version.
2. sicktoolbox_wrapper download – The home page for this package is (https://wiki.ros.org/sicktoolbox_wrapper), and the download location is: (https://github.com/ros-drivers/sicktoolbox_wrapper/tree/revert-6-kinetic-devel). I made sure to download the ‘revert-6-kinetic-devel’
3. I unzipped the downloaded packages, and placed them into Desktop/workspace/src/.
4. I rename the folders “sicktoolbox-catkin” to “sicktoolbox”, and “sicktoolbox_wrapper-revert-6-kinetic-devel” to “sicktoolbox_wrapper”. If I don’t rename the directories and continue with the original names, roscd in step 8 does not find the packages.
5. I navigate to Desktop/workspace and execute `catkin_make`. Everything runs, everything looks happy to me. The only item that is suspicious is `CMake Warning at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:166 (message): catkin_package() DEPENDS on 'Threads' but neither 'Threads_INCLUDE_DIRS' nor 'Threads_LIBRARIES' is defined.`. But even so, it’s only a warning.
6. Next I execute `source devel/setup.bash`
7. I confirm that the environment is ok with `echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` and the results are: `/home/brains/Desktop/workspace/src:/opt/ros/kinetic/share`.
8. I use tab completion on `roscd sicktoolbox` and am offered `sicktoolbox/` and `sicktoolbox_wrapper/`. I am able to use `roscd` to enter both directories.
9. Everything looks ok, and now I am finally ready to follow the sicktoolbox_wrapper tutorial (found here: https://wiki.ros.org/sicktoolbox_wrapper/Tutorials/UsingTheSicklms). The first step in tutorial is to get the dependencies and compiling the driver and rviz. However as soon as I execute `rosdep install sicktoolbox_wrapper rviz` I get the error: `ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved to system dependencies: sicktoolbox_wrapper: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [sicktoolbox]`

I did look over the readme file inside sicktoolbox_wrapper (located here: https://github.com/ros-drivers/sicktoolbox_wrapper/commit/0339280d56ecf24a496882efca08db95dd752783), but it does not mention running `$ rosdep install sicktoolbox_wrapper rviz` or `rosmake sicktoolbox_wrapper rviz`, which does not seem to make sense to me (I am pretty new to programming and ROS).

I am pretty new, and am having a really hard time installing this package, which is super critical to me. I searched for the error online, and read all the related questions and tutorials I could find, and am still stuck. Could you please suggest how to install sicktoolbox driver in Kinetic?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/297938/how-to-install-sicktoolbox-in-kinetic?/) by [BuilderMike](https://answers.ros.org/users/31958/buildermike/) on ROS Answers with karma: 247 on 2018-07-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To make everything work, follow all the steps up to step 8 (and including step 8) in the question above. Then run these two commands:

`$ rosdep install sicktoolbox rviz`

`$ rosmake sicktoolbox rviz`

and voila, the sicktoolbox driver installs, and I confirmed that this actually works. Now I can get past step 1 in the sicktoolbox_wrapper tutorial (http://wiki.ros.org/sicktoolbox_wrapper/Tutorials/UsingTheSicklms). someone should update that tutorial as I suspect it no longer applies to Kinetic.

---

Originally posted by [BuilderMike](https://answers.ros.org/users/31958/buildermike/) with karma: 247 on 2018-07-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0